# How to execute a shell script stored on remote machine from a local machine?

Tags: bash, shell, local, remote-server

I have a `script.sh` stored on remote server at some directory, which I want to run from a local computer.

How can I do that in `unix` using `ssh`?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic. No code is provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ssh` command from the local server to execute commands on the remote server. You just have to do something like this:

```
ssh [user]@[server] '[command]'
```

In your case, you are trying to execute a shell-script. You can use the same method in the following way:

```
ssh [user]@[server] /location/of/your/script.sh
```

You can also run multiple commands in this way:

```
ssh [user]@[server] '[command 1]; [command 2]; [command 3]'
```

Or you can also do something like this:

```
ssh [user]@[server] << EOF
command 1
command 2
command 3
EOF
```

Comment: is it possible to pass file from the local pc as input. Consider the simple case with `cat` `ssh user@server 'cat' local_file`. i.e. use the cat from the remote pc to display file from the local pc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have ssh access to your remote server. Type this in a terminal at the local server:

```
ssh user@remote-server /path/to/script.sh
```